# How can I read what's inside the exported backup of my Google Cloud database?

Tags: database, export, gcloud, database-backups

Sorry if this is obvious. I expected this to be a common question, but I haven't been able to find an answer in the community.

I have exported a backup of my Google Cloud database, and now I need to know what's inside. It would be great if I could manipulate that data - extract some part of it - but I would be happy if could just read it.

Am I missing something? Is this something obvious? Maybe I have made an error during the the exportation?

Thanks in advance!

1. Exported my database using gcloud CLI.
2. I tried finding ways to read what's inside, so I can verify that the data I need is there and that it is correct. I searched Google Cloud, Firebase and Googled it.

Comment: What type of database and backup is it? I believe Postgresql dumps can just be restored to a local Postgres instance with pg_restore.